# Next js project server build(jenkins+docker) failed with exit code 1

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins, next.js

I am running jenkins build error in my next js project, where as build works fine in local.

package.json structure with next 10.1.3

```json
    "node":"16.18.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "escape-html": "^1.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "fast-sass-loader": "2.0.1",
    "final-form": "^4.20.1",
    "final-form-focus": "^1.1.2",
    "i18next-fs-backend": "^1.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "v10.1.3",
    "next-compose-plugins": "2.2.0",
    "next-i18next": "8.6.0",
    "nextjs-basic-auth-middleware": "^0.1.0",
    "passport": "0.5",
    "passport-ci-oidc": "^2.0.4",
    "path-match": "^1.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-final-form": "^6.5.2",
    "react-markdown": "^5.0.3",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "sass": "1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
```

Local build as screen shot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym0KA.png)

Docker commands

```docker
RUN rm -rf .next
RUN rm -rf build
RUN yarn cache clean --all
RUN yarn build
```

Jenkins file: no change since long time

Jenkins build error during Generating static pages(.../...)

```
#16 864.3 error Command failed with exit code 1.
#16 864.3 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
#16 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c yarn build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [12/12] RUN yarn build:
------
process "/bin/sh -c yarn build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Despite updating most of my libraries, I am running into same build error in jenkins build.
Any kind of suggestion or inputs would really helpful. Thanks

I tried updating libraries, but no luck yet and not able to do RCA.

Comment: Try checking `npm` and `node` version of your system and server. Match it if they are different.